# VB.net TableAdapter.Update not updating database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-update, tableadapter

I'm adding a new row to an Access 2010 database, and attempting to update the new row using TableAdapter.Update(). The code does not throw an exception, and it does not make a successful update to the database either. I've checked the original DB for changes, the one in the project folder, and the copy that is made in bin and there are no changes to any of them. Here is my code and any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub insertRow(job As String, part As String, castDate As Date, inspectDate As Date, NCIR As Integer)
    Dim row As As_Cast_DBDataSet.As_CastRow
    Dim adapter As New As_Cast_DBDataSetTableAdapters.As_CastTableAdapter

    row = Me.DBDataSet.As_Cast.NewAs_CastRow()
    adapter = Me.As_CastTableAdapter

    row.Job_Number = job
    row.Part_Number = part
    row.Casting_Date = castDate
    row.Inspection_Date = inspectDate
    row.NCIR = NCIR

    Try
        Me.DBDataSet.As_Cast.Rows.Add(row)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        adapter.Update(Me.DBDataSet.As_Cast)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing i'd check is that the table contains a Primary Key?

Comment: And that all required fields are being set?

Comment: What value does your `Update` call return?  If it's not zero then the change IS being saved and you're just looking for it in the wrong place or at the wrong time, which is a very common mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, and jmcilhinney, the update call returns 1. So I got to poking around and found that the values were in fact updating, but were being stored in a copy in the /bin/ folder that was being overwritten every time the project was ran. I changed the path for my DB and everything's working now.